# Cannot find static file in django

Tags: python, django

My file  `view.py` contains a funtion:

```
def blog(request):
    return render(request, 'home/blog.html')
```

In my `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', blog, name='cover'),
    url('diaoibou/', blog, name='blog'),
]
```

When use the the url `r'^$`, I find the static files and my web application displays the images. But when I use the url `diaoibou`, it cannot find the statics files.

My logs:

```
[18/Sep/2018 10:04:34] "GET /diaoibou HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[18/Sep/2018 10:04:34] "GET /diaoibou/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9124
[18/Sep/2018 10:04:34] "GET /diaoibou/static/css/bootstrap.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9124
[18/Sep/2018 10:04:34] "GET /diaoibou/static/css/style.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9124
[18/Sep/2018 10:04:34] "GET /diaoibou/static/css/popup-box.css HTTP/1.1" 200 9124
[18/Sep/2018 10:04:34] "GET /diaoibou/static/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 9124
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is serving the static assets? Why have you nested them under /diaoibou?

Comment: You seem to prepend the static files with the app name. Please share the `blog.html` template.

Comment: move `url(r'^$', blog, name='cover'),` below `url('diaoibou/', blog, name='blog'),`